# creating Sign-up form on Facebook

Tags: profile, facebook

We are looking to include a sign-up form using a CiviCRM profile or some other method on our Facebook page. Does anyone have any recommendations for tools that can do this? I assume it is a matter of including the HTML code snippet  from the CiviCRM profile in iframe on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an HTML snippet for a Profile and include as an iframe. This option should show under 'more' to the right of the profile listings.

> HTML Form Snippet - If you want more control over form layout, or want to add Profile input forms to non-CiviCRM blocks, pages and/or sites...click the HTML Form Snippet action link for a Profile below - and copy and paste the HTML form code into any web page.

NOTE: there is now a setting in Administer => System Settings => Misc to enable this.

Comment: There is a discussion here about the settings https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15266/using-html-snippets-for-forms-no-longer-an-option