# Why is the `HTML Form Snippet` option missing from Profiles?

Tags: wordpress, profile, widget

I'd like to add a form/profile in a footer or sidebar widget.

I tried the Shortcode Widget plugin recommended in a Jan'18 question and placed the widget in the left column of a footer, but the form doesn't appear. I'm WP 4.9.8 and Civi 4.7.29, and here is the shortcode I put in the widget: [civicrm component="profile" gid="17" mode="create" hijack="0"]. The test shortcode "[shortcode_widget_test]" does work, so it seems to be a Civi-related problem (?).

I also saw a question from 2016 that suggested using an HTML form snippet: "Go to Administer CiviCRM > Profiles, then HTML Form Snippet under 'more' for your chosen snippet. Copy all the code there and paste it into your text widget." but I don't have that option under "more".

Can anyone help?  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML Form Snippet option will be available for profiles if the Accept profile submissions from external sites option has been set to yes –

Administer > System Settings > Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, Anil, that worked, thx!  Two questions: 1) what vulnerabilities do I open up with this setting? 2) how do I get this form/profile embedded in the widget to use the styling of the theme I'm using for the website (like it does when placed on a page thru a shortcode)?

Comment: Actually, let me revise #2 above - I see that this snippet has actually overridden my theme's style even for profiles placed on a page thru a shortcode.  Do I need to change or delete those stylesheet links I see in the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Snippet method introduces a critical security risk that you may find unacceptable. More information on that can be seen here:

- https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2016-17-manage-csrf-overrides-for-external-profile-forms

I used the Caldera Forms plugin in conjunction with the Caldera Forms CiviCRM plugin to build a simple email form that has plenty of options, and can be placed in a widget area using the built-in Caldera Forms widget. Examples of options include: auto-responder email to the person signing up, notification email to a site admin, adding the person signing up to a CiviCRM group, AJAX form submission, and lots more.

The solution hasn't gone live to a production site yet, as our client needs to approve the concept, but it looks really promising and seems more secure, and less likely to break in future Civi upgrades.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/caldera-forms/
- https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm

I have seen this and similar questions asked quite a bit. I will try and link back to this answer on some other questions that make sense... adding an email signup form to a sidebar seems like a pretty common use case, and the HTML Snippet method isn't adequate in my opinion.